# module 'torch.onnx.symbolic_helper' has no attribute 'quantized_args'

Tags: python, pytorch, torch, onnx, torchvision

while importing transforms from torchvision I am getting the following error

```
module 'torch.onnx.symbolic_helper' has no attribute 'quantized_args'
```

import that I performed

```
from torchvision import transforms
```

prior to the error it throws following warnings:

```
 OnnxExporterWarning: Symbolic function 'aten::_shape_as_tensor' already registered for opset 9. Replacing the existing function with new function. This is unexpected. Please report it on https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues.
      errors.OnnxExporterWarning,
```

versions for torch and torchvsion

```
torch==1.13.0
torchvision==0.14.0
```

Additional Info: I have cuda enabled gpu using cuda 11.8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case this was the version conflict error, try changing torch to only cpu version that should work and if  you want to stick to gpu try using cuda==11.6 along with torch==1.13.0 and torchvision==0.14.0.

```
conda install pytorch torchvision torchaudio pytorch-cuda=11.6 -c pytorch -c nvidia
```

Try referring to this link.

```
https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/
```